# How to adjust font using VB 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual studio 2008 and I need to be able to adjust a font size using an expression.
So far I have,

`IIf((Len(First(Fields!CardID.Value, "data"))> 30), "12 pt", "72 pt")`

I know I have to reference the LEN variable to get the total character size, but I'm not sure how.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have this ,, =str(60-len(First(Fields!Full_Name.Value, "data")))+ "pt" which works most of the time however for long names this dosen't. I need to be able to fill the box no matter what the size for the biggest fit

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?  And what is the 'box' that you are trying to fill?

Answer (score 2):

For Winforms, given below is a sample.  It is a bit cumbersome but it works quite well.  For this example, there is a Form with a button `Button1`, a textbox `TextBox1`, and a label `Label1`.  When `Button1` is clicked the text that is in `TextBox1` is fit into the available space of `Label1`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
     Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim fnt As New Font("Tahoma", 1, FontStyle.Regular)
  Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

  Dim i As Int32 = 0
  Dim boxWidth As Integer = Label1.Width
  Dim textWidth As Double = 0
  Dim someSmallAmountToAccountForLabelPadding As Int16 = 5

  Do While textWidth < boxWidth - someSmallAmountToAccountForLabelPadding
     i += 1
     fnt = New Font("Tahoma", i, FontStyle.Regular)
     textWidth = g.MeasureString(TextBox1.Text, fnt).Width
  Loop

  Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
  Label1.Font = fnt

  g.Dispose()

End Sub
```

[image]

---

For WPF, you don't even need any code, just a Viewbox.  The XAML shown below has a Window with a TextBox `tbx1` and a TextBlock.  Whatever you type in `tbx1` is automatically fit into the TextBlock which the Viewbox then scales up or down to fit in the available space it is in.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="20,8" Name="tbx1"/>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tbx1, Path=Text}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

You can experiment with the Stretch property of the Viewbox to achieve different effects.
[image]